# Avoid submitting delete on every key when doing hazelcast deleteAll

Tags: persistence, hazelcast

When implementing persistence on a hazelcast map, the `MapStore` interface has to be implemented. While calling `clear()` on a map, hazelcast calls `deleteAll(Collection<K> clctn)` for a distinct set of keys, that have to be deleted from the store iteratively using a delete call for every key.

This imposes a performance problem on a store that contains a large number of map entries. Unfortunately there is no way of telling the store to 'truncate' the map regardless of the keys known to hazelcast.

Does anybody know a workaround? Is it planned to support a truncate call for hazelcast MapStore?

Best regards, Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no plan to implement that. I guess what would help you is to know that clear was called? The problem here is, that clear is not like a cluster-wide atomic operation and you just use truncate on the db, it might happen that other nodes start to write data again immediately - if that makes sense.

So if every node calls truncate you might lose some never data, it depends on the use case if that is a bad thing or not.

Chris

Comment: Purpose is here, to empty a system wide cache for a certain map on demand. So it has to be a cluster-wide call to `clear`

Comment: It will be a cluster-wide call but this call is not atomic. Node 1 already executed clear, while node 2 is still pushing data and eventually node 2 calls clear. In the meantime another thread on node 1 might have started to push data again. For a simple cache this is ok but it doesn't offer any kind of guarantee nor consistency. What is not cleat to me, why there is a MapStore for a simple cache, sounds very wrong to me. A cache is meant to work fast, a MapStore prevents that behavior. Using write-behind makes the clear operation even worse.

Comment: So why then offer a store interface in the first place?

Comment: Why not? I'm not sure I get the question.

Comment: @sahlix, noctarius is questioning why your map-cache needs persistence. A cache usually doesn't require any persistence. Hazelcast offers MapStore interface, as not every map in hazelcast is used as cache...

Comment: The term 'cache' is maybe a little bit misleading here. It is more like a front-end to another machine that may or may not be available. In case it's not available, the front-end has to survive restarts, making it necessary to persist the entries in the map.